# Is there any way to block the scrolling of a WebBrowser from going outside the page

Tags: c#, html, browser, windows-phone-8

Is there any way to prevent the scroll out of page of the WebBrowser in windows phone 8?
I don't know if my question is clear so i give you an example

If i navigate to StackOverflow inside a webbrowser, even if I'm on top of the page I'm able to scroll up.
This make the topmost menu go down revealing a white block in the part over the menu.
I'm scrolling outside the page.
When I release the scroll the page return to the right position

Is there any way to prevent scrolling outside the page?
Take note that I want to still be able to scroll but i want the scroll to stop when I'm on top

Hope my english is clear

there is not very much code I can share, that's the standard way for WebBrowser to handle the scroll and I can't find a way to override that

```
<phone:WebBrowser  Source="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"/>
```

start application, scroll up
you will see that the top menu scroll down.
Is there any way to prevent the scroll outside of bound?

Comment: Please provide some code. As it is now, your question looks like "how do I configure IE/Chrome/Firefox?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok for other people reference, I respond my question

There's no easy way to do that since the manipulation events are swallowed by the webbrowser.

I found this link http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/12/a-simple-multi-page-windows-phone-7-phonegap-example/

which provide some library to get the manipulation event from the WebBrowser

To resolve the problem you (and I) still need to create an algorithm for the manipulationDelta event which I'm not sure is even feasible...